# Css padding not working properly

Tags: css, padding

I'm working in the main page of www.recaccesorios.com and I'm struggling with a padding. The vertical distance between two elements is too big and I don't know why is doing that. I'll show you the inspection with Google Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, Chrome is telling me that the top padding is 0 or null, but in the image you can see that it isn't true. What is happening?

My horrible CSS (not the whole CSS, I can't put here more than 3000 lines...):

```
#galeria {

-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
background-color: rgba(222,222,222,0.8);
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
border-radius: 4px;
/* padding-bottom: 40px; */
width: 100%;
}

#galeria > h5 {
text-align: center;
}

#noticias > h5 {
text-align: center;
}

#noticias a {
color:#555;
}

#noticias p {
text-align : justify;
padding-left:12px;
padding-right:12px;
}

#noticias {
height:292px;
}

#vistaPrevia {
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
top: 40px;
display: none;
}

#galeria > img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#galeria > span {
margin-left: 5px;
}
#noticias {

-moz-border-radius: 4px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
background-color: rgb(222,222,222); 
background-color: rgba(222,222,222,0.8);
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
border-radius: 4px;
/* padding-bottom: 40px; */
width: 100%;
}

.td-galeria {
padding-right: 6px;
padding-left: 0px;
border-color:transparent;
width:50%; 
height:300px;
}

.td-noticias {
padding-left: 6px;
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: or make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Maybe it's the surrounding element rather than the selected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is the reset on line 42 of the CSS file `vertical-align: baseline;` this seems to be causing your chrome issues.

This solves the issue:

```
#tablaInicio td {vertical-align:}
```

But it is strange.

### EDIT:

Found out why it is strange; it is a JS script causing the extra height.

Comment: Do you know how can I debug to know which JS is creating the problems?

Comment: Yeah sure NP. If you turn off JS then you see that the padding issue has gone. I know you use the script to create equal heights, but perhaps it is an option for you to remove your background styles from the div and place them on the Table-cell because these automagically have equal heights anyway

Comment: Did ya fix it already? I just looked and it was working here :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem exists in line 42 of Style.css;

remove    `vertical-align:baseline;`

and also correct

```
#tablaInicio td {vertical-align:}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your CSS to understand this better. But, I'm guessing you've declared the padding somewhere else in your code.

In your CSS file, change the padding value line to something like this:-

"padding: 0px !important";

the !important message means it will ignore any other values you try to set for padding.

I hope this helps.